# Is accessing outer class variables without creating objects safe?

Tags: java, android, inner-classes

I want to ask the if I create an outer class which have some public members and I also create an inner class inside the outer one,then is it safe to use outer class variables without instantiating it?
What will be the difference in the two scenarios?
As I have created a lot of inner classes in my application and sometimes the application doesn't work appropriately and I always suspect that it would be due to this,So I must instantiate it.
Suppose I have this class:

```
  Class x extends Activity
  {
        public sharedPreferences sx;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstantState)
        {    
             super.onCreate(savedInstantState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_x);
             sx=getSharedPreferences("name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        }
        private class y extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
        {
           @override   
           public void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
                  String name=sx.getString("name",name);
           }

           protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           }
  }
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Well, in this example, you can't call `doInBackground` unless you've instantiated `y`, and you can't instantiate `y` unless you've also instantiated `x`. So I can't see what you're asking.

Comment: I agree with David and would like to add that you cannot be sure that `sx` has been properly set in `doInBackground`. You should check that before using it.

Comment: Sorry but it is related to android and I think there is no need to instantiate x .

Comment: as `x` is an android Activity and you manually don't get an instance of it, I guess what OP means is: *is correct to call `sx` in the way shown or is better to create `x` intance inside `y` to access `sx`?*

Comment: Suppose there are many other classes and somewhere I have saved the values of the shareprefrences under same package declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Java language allows an inner class to access an outer class' private members. To bridge the gap, the compiler generates a couple of synthetic methods:

for more information with example http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PackageInner

Answer (score 0):

Well, your example code is doing UI operations right in the method that's not supposed to. If you want to do anything regarding views (Toast for example, but really anything) you'd want to do it on the `onPostExecute` and `onProgressUpdate` methods.

Accessing the `SharedPreferences` like you're doing **is fine**.

Comment: yes I wanted to know this only.Sorry for programmatic errors.If onResume is called will these values be saved?